# Compatible client-side file download

Tags: javascript, html, file, client

I'm trying to create a csv file in JavaScript that the user can download. I've found some approaches, like using the `download` attribute to specify a filename, but it is not compatible with IE. Are there any browser compatible ways to do this?

Comment: I've found https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/ useful

Comment: I've used FileSaver and modified it, writing a fallback for early version of IE (detected using navigator.userAgent) where it 'opens' the file in an iframe. Hope that helps!

Comment: will look into these, thanks

Comment: @robmarston how did you 'open' the file? I'm able to do it using the methods that FileSaver used (creating a blob, using download attribute), but when it comes to making it work for IE, I'm not sure how to specify a filename and filetype when downloading